# NSArrayController keypath binding crash

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, binding, nsarraycontroller

I bound `NSArrayController`'s content array to my File's Owner (which is my subclass of NSViewController) `device.files` key path. Both `device` and `files` are KVO-able.

When I release my view controller I've got

`[NSKeyValueObservance retain]: message sent to deallocated instance` exception (with all debugger memory options turned on)

If I put the `NSObjectController` in my xib, bound it to `FO.device` and bound `NSArrayController` to `NSObjectController` with `Controller Key = selection` and `Model key Path = files` all works great.

Can someone explain me whats wrong with binding to key path? As I know binding to a key path should observe all items in this path..

Comment: If you run your app in the Zombies template of Instruments, it should be able to show you both the stack trace of the message being sent to the deallocated instance as well as the history of retains and releases for that instance.  So, you can identify where things go wrong.

Comment: Thanks, I've never tried this template before. It detects Zombie message but there is too few information about method call..
The responsable object is `[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverRegistration) _addObserver:forProperty:options:context:]` and I can't trace the call stack. The error occurred in the `NSObject` level..

Comment: Are you testing a debug build? Have you exposed the extended detail view, which should show the stack trace for a selected event?

Comment: Yes, I test a debug version, but have no extended details neither in Instruments nor in debugger, just address (like: `An Objective-C message was sent to a deallocated object (zombie) at address: 0x1001e7770`) and responsible caller (like `[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverRegistration) _addObserver:forProperty:options:context:]`)